# Is it possible to revert to the "old" python interactive in VS Code?

Tags: python, visual-studio, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

VS Code has recently changed the style of the Python interactive window. It now looks more like a Jupyter notebook, whereas it had more of a iPython behaviour before (where you could for instance go up and down the history with the arrow keys). For a while, this could be desactivated with `"jupyter.enableNativeInteractiveWindow": false` in `settings.json`, but I now get an "Unknown configuration setting" (see attached picture).

I was just wondering if anyone has seen the same behaviour and has found a fix as I haven't yet. I've never been a fan of notebooks for research and I hope it is possible to revert to the previous style of python interactive

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turn to **Jupyter** extension, click the selection list right next to Uninstall, you may install another version:

[image]

Install `v2021.8.1195043623` then reload window, the setting is achievable.

[image]

Comment: This makes me so incredibly happy - thank you

Comment: Do you really plan to discard this feature on future release?

Comment: @e5k. In latest Jupyter, there's a setting called `"jupyter.interactiveWindowMode"`, does setting its value as `single` meet your needs?